# R get the environment created by a function at the call

Tags: r, scope

I would like to get the environment created by a function when it is runned **WITHOUT** modifying the function source (ie from outside of the function), is it possible ?

```
fn=function()
{#Here a new environment is created at each call, how to get it ?
 #This environment can be access with environment() but only (to what I know) 
 #from inside the function

  ...
}
```

I would like something like this:

```
env=some_function(fn())
```

where env is the environment id created by fn at the call.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to do with this function? I'm not sure what you expect to return from this function?

Comment: @ColinFAY It is hard to fully explain here but in short I am testing some debugging procedures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could trace the function to bind the call environment to a symbol in the global environment:

```
fn <- function() {x <- 2; 1}
trace(fn, quote(efn <<- environment()), at = 1)
fn()
#Tracing fn() step 1 
#[1] 1
untrace(fn)
efn$x
#[1] 2
```

Comment: thanks. Any suggestion to wrap it in a function such as efn=some_fn(fn())?

Comment: Ok I figured out how to do it => trace(as.character(substitute(...))[1])